# How exactly does alcohol consumption damage dendrites?

Tags: neuroscience, alcohol

How exactly does alcohol consumption damage dendrites? I'm not talking about over a long period of usage, but just one instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wernicke%E2%80%93Korsakoff_syndrome#Alcohol-thiamine_interactions

> Strong evidence suggests that ethanol interferes directly with
>   thiamine uptake in the gastrointestinal tract. Ethanol also disrupts
>   thiamine storage in the liver and the transformation of thiamine into
>   its active form.[20] The role of alcohol consumption in the
>   development of WKS has been experimentally confirmed through studies
>   in which rats were subjected to alcohol exposure and lower levels
>   thiamine through a low-thiamine diet.[21] In particular, studies have
>   demonstrated that clinical signs of the neurological problems that
>   result from thiamine deficiency develop faster in rats that have
>   received alcohol and were also deficient in thiamine than rats who did
>   not receive alcohol.[21] In another study, it was found that rats that
>   were chronically fed alcohol had significantly lower liver thiamine
>   stores than control rats. This provides an explanation for why
>   alcoholics with liver cirrhosis have a higher incidence of both
>   thiamine deficiency and WKS.[20]

[20] Todd, K. G., Hazell, A. S., & Butterworth, R. F. (1999). Alcohol thiamine interactions: an update on the pathogenesis of wernicke encephalopathy. Addiction Biology, 4, 261-272.

[21] He, X., Sullivan, E. V., Stankovic, R. K., Harper, C. G., & Pfefferbaum, A. (2007). Interaction of thiamine deficiency and voluntary alcohol consumption disrupts rat corpus collosum ultrastructure. Neuropsychopharmacology, 32, 2207-2216.

but this is of course over a long period.

for just one instance, there's no scientifical evidence AFAIK